# qmake -project scans whole drive

Tags: windows, qmake

I am trying to use qmake in a windows environment to get all files.

I used

```
qmake -project
```

to get a `src.pro` but it finishes with

```
In file C:\work\build\qt5_workdir\w\s\qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qstring.cpp, line
1696: Out of memory
```

If I start it with debug information I get lots of lines, for example:

```
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/mingw492_32/mkspecs/features/spec_pre.prf:40: entering block
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/mingw492_32/mkspecs/features/spec_pre.prf:40: evaluating test function "exists"
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/mingw492_32/mkspecs/features/spec_pre.prf:40: calling built-in exists(C:\\Qt\\5.5\\mingw492_32\\bin/sh.exe)
```

So it seems to me that qmake scans the whole partition and not only the current directory. How can I tell `qmake`that it should only scan or files below current directory?